# Duplicating an object while perfectly aligning each edge

Tags: edges

I would like to duplicate this object four times along the x axis:

[image: wot i got]

I can do this by duplicating it and manually moving it roughly into position:

[image: wot i wan]

But how do I do it properly, such that each edge of each object is perfectly aligned with the edge(s) of the object next to it? I guess the solution should also involve or allow for removing any duplicate edges between each object, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So many ways, depending ..

Assuming this is in Edit mode, and these are one-off parts already measured to fit a hole in the existing mesh, aligned to the world as shown, you could:

- Set Snap to 'Vertex, Active'
- Select the whole part, and in Vertex Mode, make one of its bottom right vertices active
- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> duplicate the part, snapping the rear vertex of the duplicated part to the corresponding front vertex of the existing one
- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> repeat the operation until the hole is filled
- With all selected, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> > 'By Distance' merge coincident vertices.

BUT.. this whole process seems a bit topsy-turvy, since you would already have had to measure up the part, somehow? Going back a couple of steps..

[image]

- In Edge Mode, Right-click > 'Subdivide' the opposing edges, adjust the cuts to 4
- <kbd>I</kbd> inset the five new faces, with the tool set to 'Individual' and 'Depth' adjusted to raise the inset faces to the desired distance
- Make tweaks afterwards?

If you had hundreds to do, or reasons to do this non-destructively, you could temporarily split the part off into a new object, and use an Array modifier, before rejoining into one object..

Comment: Right, I initially did it similar to the second approach until I got to raising each "ridge", then I started on one ridge because I didn't think of doing them all at once. That seems like a better way to do it. Good to know that it's possible to do it the other way though!

Comment: ... how do you make a vertex active when you have lots selected?

Comment: I have now duplicated the first side of the lid so that I can try the first approach you mentioned. I have all five ridges selected, but no matter which snapping mode I use, it won't snap to the edge of the other lid.

Comment: I got it to work eventually. My first issue was that snapping wasn't actually turned on! Then I used "Edge, Active" snapping. Vertex wouldn't snap for some reason.

Comment: @Mitch On your first point, I was raising all the ridges at once _in the Inset operation_ by tweaking the  'Depth' field in the  'Adjust Last Operation' panel which appears at the bottom left of the 3D view after left-clicking to accept the inset operation. To make a vertex among others active shift-left-click twice. I always have my snap set to Vertex, Active. The 'active' element is the source (moving) one.. the vertex, the target.